# added following to improve page speed to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, caching, browser, pagespeed

I input the following into my .htaccess file for www.localmarketingus.com

```
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php|xml|html)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# BEGIN Turn ETags Off
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Pragma
  Header unset ETag
</ifModule>
FileETag None
# END Turn ETags Off    

# BEGIN Compress text files
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php|xml|html)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Compress text files

# BEGIN Expire Headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c> ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"  
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
#END Expire headers

#BEGIN Vary Accept Encoding
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
#END Vary Accept Encoding

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers

# BEGIN Remove Last-Modified Header
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Last-Modified
</ifModule>
# END Remove Last-Modified Header
```

However, when i ran GTMetrix and PageSpeed insights it still said that i need to leverage browser caching and vary: accept encoding??

Is there something I did wrong in the code??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Please add this:

```
#BEGIN Vary Accept Encoding
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "private"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
#END Vary Accept Encoding
```

Instead of:

```
#BEGIN Vary Accept Encoding
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
#END Vary Accept Encoding
```

You can check out my website on gtmetrix to see I scored 100 % on the "Specify a Vary: Accept-Encoding header" test. This is my website: http://www.fotoshooting.ro/

Good luck!